# Detering effects of coffee aroma

Tags: aroma

Does coffee aroma have a detering effect on some insects, like flies, mosquitos etc.?

Are there any researches on how the 'house' insects are reacting on coffee aroma?

Comment: Coffee grounds can be used to attract cockroaches as a trap: see related: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/183/use-for-old-grounds where it is listed as a potential use for used grounds

Answer (score 2):

Though I can't find any recent evidence, it seems that research at one time shows that [caffeine can be used as an insecticide](http://www.thecrimson.com/article/1984/10/9/caffeine-kills-insects-scientist-says-pif/). However, due to the fact that [natural light exposure degrades caffeine](http://dspace.cc.tut.fi/dpub/handle/123456789/2018), it probably wouldn't make for a very good long-term solution.